# Junk Data added in json response when deployed on websphere app server 8.5 IBM

Tags: json, struts2, websphere-8

we are new at WebSphere deployment. Junk data get added in JSON response after deploying Struts 2 based web application WebSphere 8.5 on Linux platform .But same is working fine with web-logic ,tomcat ,glass-fish ..

We are not receiving any Exception in SystemOut or SystemErr.log file .

Sample response from our application :

```
{"code":0,"data":{"some data"}}¬‹í\ís›8 ÿW<|Î]yÇä ¶IÊS¿ÁIsM†áEN™8à³qÛ\'ÿû³’0–N®©›¹Ì\'SÂîJúíj -VïRR¤H:•O¤4*#éô»äa2 
f“ax6tÎ¥SõDrÇ \…Þ@:•ô»¹×¿”N¤Ñ¼çøïÝ %çÛå ˆ“yØŸÏfî¸Ä? Ð¦3wäÍGát6 Mo2v†áÈ‡ž ÑrƒN$Ï ?\õÝSoæ÷dV|ìát8÷i»r½þÜßmè* 
3pgÞ… x nè 
‡“K ³ `ôfèôû“ù8‡ž¬H§ŸnN$  
ÇÞ8 ¸ã 
}¬;îèô“ mRúá§G/š,Ý<Ö¶p?öß‡~ÏgšÓŸ÷ü~HTý?}’zS@Hèa0©~v8pwG¿š²¿B‡~-îÇ“prrW¾„±º³àl6ªnýÑ( 9³ ` Òúæf7ôÀ%ÃS 
½qàÎ°ézÎø˜6
```

Java code:

```
public class MasterDataAccess extends ActionSupport ModelDriven<AccessBean> {
    public String execute() throws Exception {
        try {
            byte[] b=jsonResp.getBytes("UTF-8");
            final InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(b,0,b.length);
            requestBean.setInputStream(inputStream);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


public class AccessBean {

    private String terminal;

    public void setTerminal(String terminal) {
        this.terminal = terminal;
    }

    public void setInputStream(final InputStream inputStream) {
        this.inputStream = inputStream;
    }
}
```

Struts XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.5//EN" "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.5.dtd"> (http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.5.dtd%27%3E) 
<struts>
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="false" />
    <package name="struts" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
        <interceptors>
            <interceptor name="SessionInterceptor" class="com.sagar.interceptors.SessionInterceptor"></interceptor>
            <interceptor name="ParameterInterceptor" class="com.sagar.interceptors.ParameterInterceptor"></interceptor>
            <interceptor name="OrderInterceptor" class="com.sagar.interceptors.OrderInterceptor"></interceptor>
            <interceptor-stack name="commonStack">
                <interceptor-ref name="timer" />
                <interceptor-ref name="SessionInterceptor" />
                <interceptor-ref name="ParameterInterceptor" />
                <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />
            </interceptor-stack>
        </interceptors>
        <global-results>
            <result name="unhandledError">/unhandledErrorPage.jsp</result>
        </global-results>
        <global-exception-mappings>
            <exception-mapping exception="java.lang.Exception" result="unhandledError" />
        </global-exception-mappings>
        <action name="masterData" class="com.sagar.common.services.MasterDataAccess">
            <interceptor-ref name="commonStack" />
            <result type="stream" name="success">
                <param name="contentType">text/plain</param>
                <param name="inputName">inputStream</param>
            </result>
        </action>
</struts>
```

Comment: You might need to post the code that generates your JSON

Comment: Please find below code added in the answer section